# Save button not storing information within the sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C`#` guys so please be kind and any help is appreciated :).

My save `button` is not retaining the information that it should on the `sql` database and I'm slightly perplexed as to why?

This is my code below...

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        InformationBindingSource.EndEdit();
        test.SaveChangesAsync();
        panel.Enabled = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        InformationBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is that on the `sql server profiler` it recognises the connection and the button also claims to store the information. Although, if a restart the project and start it back up, or look in `sql`, the information isn't there.

I have also declared the "`entity.infrastructure`" and I've just come to a stand still with no idea why it's not storing the information :(

Comment: if you check the SaveChangesAsync method you see it has an output of number of objects written to the db. (assuming test is the DBContext)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Where is your insert function or query?

Comment: Are you able to see the data in sql after you shut down your application e.g. from ssms? If you can and it is being remove when you restart the application do you have something reinitializing the database when your application starts up?

Comment: No, i'm not able to see the information at all after the application is closed.

Comment: have you tried using Hard Coding? or Are You really suppose to used builtin functions

Comment: i haven't tried hard coding, no; I don't really know how.

Comment: It's pretty messed up but I started from scratch and its working now, but i just want to thank everyone for their help. Keep up the great work guys :D.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot missing here. Have you confirmed that you can connect to the database? Your connection string is okay? Have you instantiated a SqlConnection and SqlCommand which will contain the query you're sending to the database? Have you successfully opened and closed the connection to the database?

Here's an excellent article on how to properly connect to a database and execute a query.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm